# How to choose folders with regular expressions

Tags: php, arrays, regex, file, directory

I need to choose some folders to turn them into an array and count the inside of it, to dynamically display the amount of images in it.

Right now i have a path variable:

```
$gallery_path = "assets/images/content/referenzen/gallery";
```

From there i count all images inside a specific folder inside the $gallery_path, like so:

```
  $refA_path = "assets/images/content/referenzen/gallery/refA";
  $refA = glob($refA_path . '/*.{jpeg,jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
  echo count($refA);
```

I have different folders which are named like refA, refAb and so forth. What i want to do is to choose only folders with a name of ref{number or letter}. Something like:

```
$refA_path = "assets/images/content/referenzen/gallery/{all folders with ref*}";
```

Is there anything like it in regex to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it enough to use the pattern matching of the [glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for that?

Comment: yes @xander this was right indeed, didnt know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `glob()` aswell, with GLOB_ONLYDIR option.

```
$paths_array = glob("assets/images/content/referenzen/gallery/ref*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: I think glob can also make use of character group matching like `ref[0-9]*`, if a number has to be present in the name.

Comment: @xander For sure! But OP said names would be like "ref{number or letter}", but not only one character, because examples were "refA" and "refAb". So I thought the best way would be matching `ref*`.

Comment: Yes, ref* chooses exactly the 12 folders in there and leave all the other files in it untouched. So, it works how i need it to be. Thank you for the GLOB_ONLYDIR tipp. I didnt know this so far.